# What prevents an efficient Haskell virtual machine (like JVM)?

Tags: haskell, jvm, vm-implementation

I have been wondering, what prevents the development of an efficient virtual machine like JVM or PyPy for Haskell (except maybe development effort)? Is it the language structure? I think languages, that are harder to interpret efficiently (like Python, being very dynamic), already have decent VMs.

Also, if nothing is obstructing such an implementation, would STG be a good target "bytecode", since all optimizations are done on Core?

Are there any articles or blog posts that discuss this topic?

EDITs:

- I am aware of [HaLVM](http://halvm.org/wiki/), but I don't think it is what I mean.
- I am also aware of `runhaskell`, but it is not efficient at all.

Comment: why build a new virtual machine? you could compile to JVM..

Comment: @yi_H I remember reading some research somewhere that tried to compile Haskell to JVM but somehow concluded that they were incompatible..

Comment: they aren't.. JVM is a generic virtual machine, you can theoretically compile any language to it. maybe not the best for performance, but it would work.

Comment: @yi_H That's what I meant.. Performance. I didn't mean computational power of course :). Also, I think JVM is tuned to run OO (strict) languages. I think the way the JVM garbage collector operates might really get in the way of any Haskell JVM backend. But these are all just my guesses.

Comment: The JVM doesn't really do tail recursion, which is kind of critical for Haskell.

Comment: AFAIK, GHC now does not do tail call optimization either (except in limited scenarios), I think the semantics do not allow it.

Comment: That's not even a little bit true; see, for example, http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/smoking-fast-haskell-code-using-ghcs-new-llvm-codegen/ which gets optimized so well precisely because it's a tail call.

Comment: GHC _does_ tail call optimization whenever possible! It's just that tail calls are not the most effective in some situations (due to laziness).

Comment: 1) GHC does it 2) you don't need JVM tail call optimization, you can emit code that's already optimized.

Comment: Why create a VM for Haskell when it already compiles to quite efficient native code?

Comment: @LouisWasserman OK, that came out wrong. I meant that TCO is not that big of a deal in GHC (lazy semantics), I thought that the scenarios where TCO is applicable are limited.. I think I was wrong, I will read better about that. But yi_H makes a good point that optimized code can be emitted..

Comment: Why does Java do it? I don't think it is difficult to generate efficient native code from Java.. I think it's a design choice, being able to "compile once and run everywhere".

Comment: @yi_H, the main two approaches for compiling a functional language to a language or VM without proper tail calls is (1) as one big function, or (2) using trampolines. Neither is really an option on the JVM. The costs of closures, thunks and allocation in general are other blockers. Despite the hype, the JVM is far from being a generic VM.

Comment: @yi_H: Remember that tail recursion also applies to mutually recursive functions. In this case it is harder to turn the optimization into an iterative loop.

Comment: @Andreas Rossberg - and yet Scala, Clojure and Frege compile and run fine on the JVM

Comment: @Ingo: Scala does _not_ do tail call optimization in the general case, which is a known problem. Also, it's performance for functional code is far from great. I don't know what Clojure does, but would be surprised if it is full TCO.

Comment: @missingo: tail recursion is just a special case. For functional programming you generally want full tail call optimization. That includes calls to first-class functions, where the callee is not known at compile time.

Comment: @Andreas - the TCO thing is IMHO not *that* important anymore, regrettable as the inability of the JVM to support it may be. When you are limited to 64K words for the heap and the stack, then it is indeed a show stopper. Not so if you can give 1, 2 or even 4m of stack space.

Comment: @Ingo: I disagree, for some of the more interesting FP techniques TCO is crucial. Consider continuation passing style as just one example. Growing the stack is no solution, it has to work in constant space.

Comment: @Andreas - I think CPS is not a problem in non-strict languages, regardless whether the VM supports TC or not. Don't know how Scala and CLojure go about it. But then, it is not exactly the most popular style today.

Comment: @Ingo: How is it not a problem? In CPS, no call ever returns.

Comment: @Andreas - it seems so, at least. :) but in a non-strict language the compiler can decide that a tail call is too expensive and can return a thunk instead of actually calling the function. This will also hold for the continuations passed.

Comment: @Ingo: I see. But OTOH, thunkification is particularly costly on the JVM, isn't it?

Comment: Lazyness certainly has a cost. I have no data, however, whether this cost is higher on the JVM than elsewhere.

Comment: http://tom.lokhorst.eu/uhc-clr

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What prevents an efficient Haskell virtual machine?

Nothing - there already has been one, Daan Leijen's LVM. It was efficient enough to be used for the runtime system of Helium (the Haskell "teaching language" from Utrecht University).

That said I don't know if it is used these days, so the question *"What prevents an efficient Haskell virtual machine?"* could be answered as *manpower, continuous investment*, etc. When Haskell already has a good compiler, a good VM is a luxury as Paulo Pinto noted already.

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of any technical restriction applying here. There is a language called [Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege/), semanticaly close to Haskell, that targets JVM. So it is just that nobody has considered so far that a Haskell-to-JVM compiler was worth the effort. Indeed, as a JVM-skeptic, I wonder what that would bring. If it is just intermediate language portability, I'd rather work on LLVM or on a pre-built binary farm.

Comment: There have been efforts to target Haskell for the JVM (eg search LambdaVM) but they all seem stuck.

Comment: iinm, Frege actually compiles to Java, which compiles to JVM bytecode. Some of the fundamental differences between Frege and Haskell are the primitive types: Frege uses Java's String, int, etc, while Haskell specifies them differently.

Comment: @Dan - String is not exactly a primitive type in Haskell, is it? Concerning int, the Haskell Standard does not mandate how int is to be implemented, I bet Haskell uses C ints for that.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a way to post a comment, and this is maybe even more of an anti-VM than a native-code compiler is, but the OP might be interested in the [Reduceron.](http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/reduceron/)

Answer (score 5):

[UHC](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/UHC) has a Javascript backend which of course runs on a browser's Javascript engine. I mean I don't see anything stopping Haskell from targeting different backends. In fact, I think UHC was designed to make it easy to target different backends.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. See [lambdachine](https://github.com/nominolo/lambdachine). Here're some [short notes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HaskellImplementorsWorkshop/2012/Schilling).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stops Haskell from having a VM. Haskell works beautifully on the JVM and can be even faster than GHC **after JIT warmup** in cases where the generated code hits the sweet spot of the JIT compiler. See [Eta](https://github.com/typelead/eta), a project that brings full GHC 7.10.3 Haskell onto the JVM with type-safe Java interop. It just requires lots of patience and time to work on.